# How to post data via ajax with asp.net web pages (razor)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-webpages

I've started a sample projet using the tutorials located here, http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/getting-started

Which is great, I'd prefer to use this sort of functionality to serve pages instead of the mvc controller method.  But I still want to post data back to the server using jquery ajax calls.

I'm thinking I have to implement an mvc controller that handles just my ajax requests and doesnt serve pages.

Is this a logical approach or is there a better way?  If it is logical, does anyone have a link on how to add this type of controller functionality to an existing asp.net web pages project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web API (*"doesn't serve pages"*) would be the way to go. I personally haven't mixed it with WebPages so [this reference](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/261/integrating-web-api-with-asp-net-razor-web-pages) should be helpful.

Not as "good", but still doable, depending on what your needs are, "it's still ASP.Net", so good old `ashx` (generic handler to process your requests) would work too, though, this is probably if you have simple/few "services" you want to use/invoke...

Hth...

Comment: yeah, i think this is the way to go, ive used web api in the past for a specific purpose, but maybe i need to use it more often in the future, thanks